# sitecore language cookie overwrite in arabic version

Tags: multilingual, pipelines, language-fallback, cookies

I am using `Sitecore 10` with `JSS` `Angular` app, I need to set site language `cookie` **{{mysite}}#lang** to be **HttpOnly** so I have created the `HttpRequest` pipeline `processor`.

```
public class CookieProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public List<string> Sites { get; set; }
    public CookieProcessor()
    {
        Sites = new List<string>();
    }
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (!Sites.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name))
            return;
        
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Sitecore.Context.Site.Name+"#lang"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

    }
}
```

and this the `patch` config file.

> 

```
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <httpRequestBegin>
            <processor type="Maqta.Project.Website.CookieProcessor,Maqta.Project.Website"
                       patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" resolve="true">
                
            </processor>
        </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

This change works fine for the English version but when I navigate to the Arabic version, it is set correctly first but gets overwritten after the page is fully loaded.

Maybe this happens when the cookie value is set to be "ar" instead of "en"

so any idea when cookie value set to be "ar" and if there are pipelines run after this??

Note: also I have tried to use this processor

> processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']

instead of **ItemResolver** but still the same issue

Comment: Not sure if there is enough information to answer your question I think it would need a network trace and some info on how the language gets resolved in requests from your Angular app. Did you consider setting the HttpOnly attribute through an outbound rewrite rule? This could be simpler, doing these things through pipelines always have many scenarios which can cause issues.

Comment: Are you saying that the Arabic language cookie is overwritten by the English language cookie once the page loads?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65946560/how-to-set-httponly-and-secure-lang-sitecore-cookie